# MVC Input Text SearchPage

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

```
<input id="filter" type="text" placeholder="Search in list" class="form-control">
```

I have a ready-made template I want to use the search part in this template. But I can not include the feature. How to include `SeachString` function this code

```
@Html.TextBox("SearchString")
```

Comment: Include what feature?

Comment: what is SeachString function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Html.TextBox("SearchString",null , new { placeholder = "Search in list", @class ="form-control" })
```

> I could not tell the problem right. That i wanted to do. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input id="filter" type="text" placeholder="Search in list" class="form-control">
```

I think you want to search the list for a given input text.

You can call javascript function on *{onkeydown,onkeypress,onkeyup}* based on the requirement

[Javascript Events](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_events.asp)

You can also use 
 [Jquery Events](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events_examples.asp)

```
@Html.TextBox("SearchString")
```

Instead use `@Html.TextBox("filter", null, new {@onkeydown = "searchString();" })`

@Html.TextBox has Html Attribute as a parameter.